# Microsoft Excel - Comparing 2 Column and Delete Duplicate by Row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, duplicates, powerquery

I am facing an issue where I need to compare column X and column Y, if X=Y then I want to delete that row. But if X≠Y then just leave it there as I need to correct it manually. I try to find any reference but to no avail.

[Example of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyYBg.png)

I try using PowerQuery, because the name list were scattered, after sorting up to X=Y, there are some data that wasnt right because it is comparing to almost identical name. I try to use 'remove duplicate' but nothing happened as it only remove if the column has the same data in multiple row.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a Helper column with the formula `Xn=Yn`.  Then filter the table on `False`

Comment: Yep, currently just doing that. Looking forward to learn any other method.

Comment: In Power Query you can just use the `Table.SelectRows` function comparing each row.

Answer (score 0):

For another method that does not involve a helper column, you can use the `Table.SelectRows` function of Power Query:

```
let

//sample data
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[x="Johnny White", y="Johnny White"],
        [x= "Black Mmamba", y= "Black Mamba"],
        [x="Tom Evans", y="Tom Evans"],
        [x="Britney Blue",y="Britney Blue"],
        [x="White Kingdom", y="Wine Kingdom"],
        [x="Daniel Zack", y="Daniel Zack"]},
        type table[x=Text.Type,y=Text.Type]),

//select rows where data not the same in each column
    remDupes = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [x] <> [y])

in
    remDupes
```

***Source***
[image]

***Dupes Removed***
[image]